# is there a function to convert utf-8 to integer in python?

Tags: python, utf-8

is there any python function to convert utf-8 to int. i can go from int to utf-8 but don't know how to get back.

```
num = 169
a=chr(169).encode('utf-8')
print(a)
print(a.decode('utf-8'))
```

this code outputs:

```
b'\xc2\xa9'
©
```

i need to go back to 169. Can anyone guide me how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html?highlight=ord#ord) function.

```
>>> ord(a.decode('utf-8'))
169
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ord` function

```
num = 169
a=chr(169).encode('utf-8')
print(ord(a.decode('utf-8')))
```